# Tools to Migrate VB6 Data Reports to Crystal Reports?

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports, vb6-migration

Hi
I need to automate the migration of VB6 Data Reports to Crystal Reports, which is now being done manually, is there any tool available to do this (or) is there a way to create one.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no conversion tools to migrate VB6 Data Reports to Crystal Reports.

When you ask "is there a way to create one"... yes, anything is possible, but it's probably not worth the effort in this case.

Comment: Crystal Reports itself offers an import from a Data Report.